# C Language program executable file extention naming convention ( a.out )

Tags: c, linux, compilation, naming-conventions, naming

Are there good practices or preferred industry standard conventions on *how to name (what would be named by default as) a.out files, especially in terms of their extensions?*

If it depends on the platform, I'd like to know especially for Linux. Technically I won't even need an extension, and most modern shell helps identify executable files by green color, nevertheless people would add .sh for bash shell scripts like **scriptName.sh**.

---

**Example:** I think the extention **.exe** adds value here rather than having no extention. But will this freak out Linux users? Perhaps **.out** is better? But will it be intuitive for non-C-programmers?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john    46 Oct  9 15:18 coolProgram.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john    80 Oct  9 15:20 coolProgram.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 john john 16576 Oct  9 15:28 coolProgram.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john  1464 Oct  9 15:21 coolProgram.o
```

Comment: Windows users seem to think extensions mean something. There have been many hacks over the years by naming malware foo.jpg or similar to get past filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extension will most likely have the opposite effect of what you want. The general expectation is that an executable has no extension (`a.out` being the obvious exception) and, if it does, especially if it's `.exe`, users are likely to have learnt to ignore it.